# Access the Digital wellbeing information from local device

Tags: xiaomi, miui, android-10

Google has implemented Digital wellbeing as part of Android pie through its Beta experience. This app captures user interactions and creates nice charts for users to understand how much was screen on time and how many times the phone was unlocked and how many apps were used in what proportion during the day, in a week etc.

I wanted to view this data not as a chart but as raw format. Where can I find this information on local device?

If not locally available can we download it from any google service?

Please suggest.[image]